# Generating(ish) a free monoid

Tags: monoid

Let $G=\langle a,b\rangle$ be a free monoid generated by $a,b$. In other words, all possible words made up of $a,b$. Say S is a set of pairs of elements of $G$, say $S=\{(aa,bb),(a,ab)\}$, now we can generate another set $S^*$ from $S$ by concatenating the pairs as many times as we want. So $(aa,bb)$ can be used to create words such as $aabb$, $aabbaabb$,$aaaabb$ etc. Similarly $(a,ab)$ can generate essentially any word that does not have two $b$'s next to each other. My question is, what are some sufficient conditions on $S$ to guarantee $G\setminus\{a,b,ab\} \subset S^*$? Is what I am saying a concept people even study?

Any ideas, references would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your notation $S^*$ is a bit misleading. So let me first restate your question (as I understand it). Let $A = \{a,b\}$, $L = A^* \setminus \{a, b, ab\}$ and let
$$
S = \{(u_1, v_1), (u_2, v_2), \ldots, (u_n, v_n) \}
$$
be a finite set of pair of words of $A^*$. You are asking for some sufficient condition on $S$ to guarantee that
$$
L \subseteq \{u_1, v_1\}^* \cup \{u_2, v_2\}^* \cup \dotsm \cup \{u_n, v_n\}^*
$$
**Theorem**. This happens if and only if one of the sets $\{u_i, v_i\}$ is equal to $A$.

**Proof**. The condition is clearly sufficient. To prove it is also necessary, first recall that a subset $P$ of $A^*$ is *dense* if, for every word $w \in A^*$, $A^*wA^* \cap P \not= \emptyset$. It is *nondense* otherwise. For instance, $L$ is dense.

**Step 1**. Let $u, v \in A^*$. Then $\{u,v\}^*$ is dense if and only if $\{u,v\} = A$.

Let $n = 1 + 2\max\{|u|, |v|\}$. If $\{u,v\}^*$ is dense, there exist two words $x$ and $y$ such that $xa^ny \in X^*$. It follows that $u$ or $v$ is of the form $a^i$ for some $i > 0$. A similar argument shows that $u$ or $v$ is of the form $b^j$ for some $j > 0$. Thus $\{u, v\} = \{a^i, b^j\}$. I let you now verify that $\{u, v\}^*$ is dense if and only if $i = j = 1$.

**Step 2**. If $\{u_1, v_1\}^*, \{u_2, v_2\}^*, \dotsm \{u_n, v_n\}^*$ are nondense, then so is $\{u_1, v_1\}^* \cup \{u_2, v_2\}^* \cup \dotsm \cup \{u_n, v_n\}^*$.

Indeed, if $\{u_1, v_1\}^* \cap A^*w_1A^* = \emptyset$, $\{u_2, v_2\}^* \cap A^*w_2A^* = \emptyset$, $\dots$, $\{u_n, v_n\}^* \cap A^*w_nA^* = \emptyset$, then
$$
\bigl(\{u_1, v_1\}^* \cup \{u_2, v_2\}^* \cup \dotsm \cup \{u_n, v_n\}^*\bigr) \cap A^*w_1w_2 \dotsm w_nA^* = \emptyset
$$
**Final step**. If none of the sets $\{u_i, v_i\}$ is equal to $A$, then the sets $\{u_i, v_i\}^*$ are nondense by Step 1, and so is their union by Step 2. Thus this union cannot contain the dense set $L$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Doesn't this show my set S has to be infinite for it not to contain $\{a,b\}$? I am okay with $S$ being an infinite set.

Comment: Yes, your set $S$ has to be infinite, but this is of course not a sufficient condition.

Comment: By the way, if you are satisfied with my answer, you have the possibility to [accept it](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: To be frank, I assumed $S$ had to be infinite. I was wondering what would be the sufficient conditions on $S$ to guarantee the result. Even a name for such an $S$ (in literature) or an example that works would be extremely helpful.